# Entity Framework POCO and Self Tracking entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

Hello
I wonder what's the difference between standard EF objects, POCO and Self Tracking Entities. I was looking the web but couldn't find a valuable introduction. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you get when you type "what's the difference between POCO and Self Tracking Entities" into a search engine???

Answer (score 1):

POCO is plain class with only mapped fields. STE is very similar but in advance it contains logic implemented to each property and some collections which are used to tracking changes made to entity.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? or do you have a link for any introduction article? Thanks